# Прозу перебивают стихи "столбиком"; какой знак при возврате к прозе?

Tags: пунктуация, прямая-речь

> К тому же музыку к нашему «Дубровскому» написал замечательный
>   театральный композитор Николай Морозов. Очень интересное музыкальное
>   переложение создал он для пушкинских стихотворных переводов цикла
>   «Песни западных славян». В спектакле прозвучало большинство из них –
>   на оригинальную, стилизованную под народную, музыку. Я много лет
>   играла Машу, и всякий раз под венчальную песнь:
>
> *Что ты ржёшь, мой конь ретивый,*
>
> *Что ты шею опустил,*
>
> *Не потряхиваешь гривой,*
>
> *Не грызёшь своих удил?*
>
> в тот момент, когда меня обряжали к свадьбе, искренне рыдала –
>   настолько щемящей и печальной была эта мелодия.

Пожалуйста, знаки: после "песнь" (согласна с двоеточием) и после "удил" (неужто тире?).

СПАСИБО!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если после стихотворной цитаты текст продолжается, то в конце стихотворной цитаты ставится тире:

**В строках стихотворения:**
*Всему пора: уж двадцать пятый раз

Мы празднуем лицея день заветный.

Прошли года чредою незаметной,

И как они переменили нас!
Не даром - нет! - промчалась четверть века!

Не сетуйте: таков судьбы закон;

Вращается весь мир вкруг человека, -

Ужель один недвижим будет он ? -*
**идея развития раскрыта Пушкиным как закон жизни, отразивший и его собственный личный опыт.**

[**Знаки препинания при цитировании**](http://www.yaklass.ru/p/russky-yazik/11-klass/predlozheniia-s-chuzhoi-rechiu-10913/znaki-prepinaniia-pri-tcitatakh-11241/re-10eaa08f-17b6-453c-948a-d44ec0ace409)

Answer (score 2):

Да, это так: если после стихотворной цитаты текст продолжается, то тире ставится в конце стихотворной строки.

А вот после уточняющего определения запятая не обязательна: "стилизованную под народную музыку"